# How to tell Intellij the file base when unshelving?

Tags: intellij-idea

I shelved files using Intellij with the intention of separating changes made in Master into separate branches.  On trying to "unshelve", Intellij is telling me it cannot find the file base for many of my files.

For example, the Intellij "Unshelve Changes" dialog is complaining about files as:

> C:\Users\rcoe\intellij-workspace\proj\D:\cygwin64\home\rcoe\git\proj  14 files

When I remap the 14 files and tell Intellij to remove files from the shelf that have been successfully unshelved, it fails to unshelf any.  I am not able to unshelve any of these files.  A huge problem, as my shelf contains many more than just these 14 files, as I have a maven multi module project and this problem exists across all of them.

When I manually remap the files inside the Unshelve Changes dialog, Intellij does show the base as being changed.  But closing the dialog doesn't change a thing.  Any help on making this work would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I managed to remove 14 of 16 files that I needed.  I found that by selecting one file at a time, I could unshelve each file.  I did not have to re-do the manual mapping process.  It seems the two files that refuse to get re-mapped were causing the others to not get unshelved.  There is nothing out of the ordinary with the last two files.  When I try to unshelve and then find a new base for the files, the file chooser dialog takes me right to the files.

Comment: It is impossible to say anything without details about file paths and changes they have, and the logs. If remapping or resetting the directory for those 2 files does not work, it could be a bug, so worth reporting to support or JetBrains tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues with logs and other details attached

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitriy.  There's not enough path information in the quoted path that Intellij shows me in the "remap base" dialog?  In any event, I've deleted those files from the shelf.  I found that if I remapped the file and then showed the diff to the index, I could see that the files were effectively untouched.  One file did have a format change, a line feed, in the xml declaration on the first line.  The other file was a javascript file that was unchanged.  Note that I couldn't diff the file from the shelf view. It had to be remapped in the dialog and diff'd while it was open.